# sorting a data table column containing timestamp with time zone

Tags: c#, datetime, oracle11g, timezone

I have a grid that is populated using an Oracle 11g query that returns a TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE field along with other fields. 
When I select a date range for data to be displayed that goes from 12/26/2014 to 1/5/2015, and then try to sort by this column (asc or desc), it does not sort properly. For example, in desc order it displays from 01/01 to 01/05 and then from 12/26 to 12/31. Looks like string sorting.

I am guessing a TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE field that contains a value like 21-JAN-2015 18:17:16:00000 USA/EASTERN is not recognized as a date-time but rather a string. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: So you are retrieving a number of columns, and provide the option to re-order them after retrieval from the database? Your grid does not allow to indicate a column's datatype? Can you add a hidden column to be used for ordering an overt one? Or present the column in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24…" format (for which string ordering would work)?

Comment: I do have a hidden column that contains the nicely formatted version of this timestamp with time column. It displays the data as "01/21/2015 18:17:16 EST"; but this is used as a presentation part sine it is string. The data itself (the timestamp with time zone) needs to be used for sorting. I cannot use the string version for sorting since it will sort like string and not date-time. I need to be able to display the time zone in this column.

Comment: How is this query different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118242/date-time-format-with-time-zone ?

Comment: There is a number of options: (i) Rely on the database to sort the data correctly - which you might want to prevent for performance reasons. (ii) Instruct the grid to handle the timestamp column as such (and not as a string column) - which might not be possible. (iia) Use a different grid component, which handles date columns properly.  (iii) Use a hidden (string) column with the timestamp formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24…" for sorting. (iv) Write your own sort routine.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I had: a hidden column that stored nicely formatted dates (strings) and column itself had the date/time data. I realized the reason I could not sort, even though it was date/time value was because I was using  "adapter.SafeMapping.Add("*", typeof(string));" for the dataset so I was always ending up with strings no matter what. Removed it and all is fine. I would have marked your response as answer but it is a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Turning a comment into an answer:</sub>

There is a number of options:
(i) Rely on the database to sort the data correctly - which you might want to prevent for performance reasons.
(ii) Instruct the grid to handle the timestamp column as such (and not as a string column) - which might not be possible.
(iia) Use a different grid component, which handles date columns properly.
(iii) Use a hidden (string) column with the timestamp formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24…' for sorting.
(iv) Write your own sort routine.

Feel free to provide more detail if and as you see fit.